# Find integral solution using congruence modulo.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Find integral solution to $a^3 - 1100 =b^3$ using modular arithmetic.

No integral solutions for this exist, so how to prove using modular arithmetic?

Earlier I had asked about $a$ and $b$ being raised to second power, but because of a mistake I was downvoted. This is the second part to that question.

Comment: "modulo" **what**?

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting me. If there is some improvement to the question i can make please tell me.

Comment: its says to prove using modular arithmetic, i changed that congruence modulo. It dosent specify. In this question i have to prove no such integral solutions exist.

Comment: An obvious beginning is to write the equation as $a^3- b^3= (a- b)(a^2+ ab+ b^2)= 1100$ and think about different ways to factor $1100= 11(100)= 2^2(5^2)(11)$.

Comment: I have already done that and proved no such integral solutions exist. However, the question mentions the use of modular arithmetic to prove this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I suppose you are looking for factors of $1100$, which are zero divisors modulo $1100$

Comment: Yes, I think so. so i have to prove there arent any integral number that do so.

Comment: I don't see a  straightforward congruence approach.  In the case of $a^2-b^2=110$ , it was natural to work $\pmod 4$ .  Here the obvious thing to try would be $\pmod 8$, but I don't see how that works.  $1100\equiv 4\pmod 8$ but , say, $5^3-1^3\equiv 4 \pmod 8$ so there is no cheap contradiction.  As before, factoring looks easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably notice that the map $x\mapsto x^3\pmod {11}$ is injective, because $0^3, 1^3, 2^3,\ldots, 10^3$ are all different $\pmod{11}$. Thus, if $a^3\equiv b^3\pmod{11}$, then $a\equiv b\pmod{11}$, in other words $11\mid a-b$.

Now where to go from there - not sure. I think a lot can be concluded by just using the arguments of "size". For example, obviously $a\gt b$, so we must have $a\ge b+11$. Imagine $b\ge 0$. then, $1100=a^3-b^3\ge (b+11)^3-b^3=33b^2+363b+1331\ge 1331\gt 1100$. This eliminates the case where $a$ and $b$ are both positive. The case where both are negative are analogous. Finally, say $a$ is positive and $b$ is negative, then we have $1100 = a^3-b^3=a^3+(-b)^3$ and so $|a|, |b|\le \sqrt[3]{1100}<11$ and this leaves just a few cases to investigate : $(a,b)\in\{(10,-1),(9,-2),\ldots,(1,-10)\}$ - out of which only half are worth checking, as the other half are the same (e.g. $10^3-(-1)^3=1^3-(-10)^3$).